# Terraform failing with Invalid for_each argument / the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings

Tags: foreach, terraform

When running terraform plan I get the following error:
The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple.

I'm trying to create buckets, but either allow the user to provide a kms key or looking it up for them.

```txt
│ Error: Invalid for_each argument
│ 
│   on ../ec2-pattern/main.tf line 39, in module "s3_bucket":
│  329:   for_each = local.s3_bucket_list
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.s3_bucket_list is tuple with 1 element
│ 
│ The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument 
| must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple.
```

```
dev.tfvars

s3_buckets = {
  bucket1 : {

    policy_bucket_modify_arns_csv = "s3-policy-arns/s3-policy-modify-arns.csv"
    policy_bucket_read_arns_csv   = "s3-policy-arns/s3-policy-read-arns.csv"
    bucket_suffix                 = "test"
    contains_pci_info             = false
  }
}
```

```
main.tf

locals {
  s3_bucket_list = flatten([
    for k, v in var.s3_buckets :
    merge(v, { kms_master_key_id = lookup(v, "kms_master_key_id", null), kms_master_key_id = module.datasource-module.data.s3_kms.arn_alias })

  ])
}

module "s3_bucket" {

  for_each = local.s3_bucket_list

  create_bucket                 = each.value.create_bucket
  policy_bucket_read_arns_csv   = each.value.policy_bucket_read_arns_csv
  policy_bucket_modify_arns_csv = each.value.policy_bucket_modify_arns_csv
  kms_master_key_id             = each.value.kms_master_key_id
}

variable "s3_buckets" {
  description = "A map of all buckets"
  type        = any
  default     = {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems clear:

> given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable ... must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple...

To troubleshoot something like that you have to output your `s3_bucket_list` so you can confirm is the correct type, in your case your output is a list, you are doing `flatten([` that only works on a list:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten

Here is how I would change your code:

```
variable "s3_buckets" {
  default = {
    bucket1 : {
      bucket_suffix     = "test"
      contains_pci_info = false
    }
    bucket2 : {
      bucket_suffix     = "abc"
      contains_pci_info = true
      kms_master_key_id = "123"
    }
  }
}

locals {
  s3_bucket_list = {
    for k, v in var.s3_buckets :
    k => merge(v, { kms_master_key_id = lookup(v, "kms_master_key_id", "foo") })
  }
}

output "s3_bucket_list" {
  value = local.s3_bucket_list
}
```

If you do a terraform plan on that we get

```txt
Changes to Outputs:
  + s3_bucket_list = {
      + bucket1 = {
          + bucket_suffix     = "test"
          + contains_pci_info = false
          + kms_master_key_id = "foo"
        }
      + bucket2 = {
          + bucket_suffix     = "abc"
          + contains_pci_info = true
          + kms_master_key_id = "123"
        }
    }
```

that is a proper map that we can use in the `for_each` ...
things I've changed:

- added one more element to the variable s3_buckets to show better output
- remove the `flatten`, your structure is flat, no clue why you needed that
- in the `lookup` I changed the null for `foo` you can put any default you want there, like what you had `module.datasource-module.data.s3_kms.arn_alias`
- in the return of the loop now we do `k => ...` that creates the map structure and we are keeping the original key from s3_buckets

Last thought now with this change maybe you should not name it `s3_bucket_list` since that is not a list.  I hope that is all clear enough.